# How exactly sockets are handled in C on windows?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock2

So, I'm having a problem, I'm trying to do a simple c server-client, where basically a client connects to the server, and from time to time the server pings the client, shouldn't be this complicated, but I'm being met with a strange behaviour from both "select", "send" and "recv".

The server code is (without the whole connection part) basically this:

```c
while (1) {
        read_set = set; write_set = set; error_set = set; timeout = ref_timeout;
        int result = select(NULL, &read_set, &write_set, &error_set, &timeout); //I'm on windows that's why the first parameter is null
        if (result < 0) {
            puts("Error select");
            return 1;
        }
        if (result == 0) puts("timed out");
        else {
            for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
                SOCKET i = sockets[index];
                if (FD_ISSET(i, &error_set)) {
                    printf("%zu error\n", i);
                    FD_CLR(i, &set);
                    closesocket(i);
                }

                if (FD_ISSET(i, &write_set)) {
                    const char* ping = "PING";
                    int size = send(i, ping, strlen(ping)+1, 0);
                    printf("%d bytes sent\n", size);
                    if (size < 0) {
                        puts("Error send");
                        closesocket(i);
                        FD_CLR(i, &set);
                    }
                    send(i, NULL, 0, 0);
                }

                if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_set)) {
                    if (i == listen_socket){
                        struct sockaddr addr;
                        int addrlen;
                        SOCKET new_socket = accept(listen_socket, &addr, &addrlen);
                        FD_SET(new_socket, &set);
                        if (new_socket > biggest) biggest = new_socket;
                        printf("new conn %zu\n", new_socket);
                        sockets[1] = new_socket;
                    }
                    else {
                        char msg[100];
                        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
                        if (recv(i, msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0) {
                            closesocket(i);
                            FD_CLR(i, &set);
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("%zu %s\n", i, msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And the client code (without the connection part) is:

```c
    char buffer[100];
    const char* pong = "PONG";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        int result = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (result < 0) {
            puts("something went wrong receiving");
            closesocket(client_socket);
            return 1;
        }
        if (send(client_socket, pong, strlen(pong)+1, 0) < 0) {
            puts("something went wrong sending");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("msg: %s\n", buffer);
        Sleep(10000);
    }
```

The behaviour I would expect is, whenever the client block from recv, the select on the server returns with the client socket on the write_set, the server writes the 5 bytes to the client, reads the 5 bytes, and then blocks until the next recv from the client.

But that's not what's happening, after the first recv, the server keeps writing 5 bytes, it receives "PONG" correctly, but doesn't stop writing to the client.

[image: Output]

And I know it is writing to the client because when I kill the client process the send immediately fails.

Is this windows being weird? Am I not understanding how to use select? How can the client tell the server it's not up to reading after the first recv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..., whenever the client block from recv, the select on the server returns with the client socket on the write_set, the server writes the 5 bytes to the client, reads the 5 bytes,

There is no kind of notification to the server if the client waits for data in `recv`. There is no other tight coupling between `send` on one side and `recv` on the other.`recv`, `send` and `select` all only work on the send and receive buffers of the socket:

- `recv` will return data from the sockets receive buffer. Note that it might not return all data requested if there are not as much data in the buffer, so check the return value for how much was actually read. It will block if there are no data in the buffer until the operating system has received such data and put it into the buffer.
- `send` will return if there was enough space in the sockets send buffer to place the new data - no matter if the peer is currently calling `recv`. Note that there might not be space for all data, so you need to check what `send` returns to find out how many data were actually placed in the send buffer. `send` will block if there is no space in the buffer and wait until the operating system has made some space by sending the data to the peer.
- `select` will return a socket as readable if there are any data in the sockets receive buffer.
- `select` will return a socket as writable if there is space in the sockets send buffer for new data

Comment: Select returning a socket as readable is working perfectly, the problem is, even if I limit the send buffer size (using the sockopt SO_SNDBUF) the server keeps sending the data even though I would expect the buffer to be full.

Comment: @FredEsch: The size of the send buffer is often more of  a suggestion. Apart from that the OS takes data from the send buffer to transmit these to the peer. So you have to the send buffer also the amount of data which might be in transmit (TCP window) and the amount of data which can be stored in the peers socket receive buffer.

Comment: @FredEsch A socket is writable as long as its send buffer is not full AND the peer socket's receive buffer is not full. So, even if the client's receive buffer is full, the server's kernel will still accept new data until the send buffer is also full. So you might consider adding a per-socket timer to your server logic so you are sending pings only at regular intervals, not just whenever sockets are writable. Send a ping, start a timer. Receive a pong, reset the timer. Send the next ping when the timer elapses. Repeat

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is exactly what I was looking for, understanding the socket was part of it, but I also needed some kind of solution to my situation, your sugestion was what I needed to formulate something that worked for me, thank you very much. Also, thanks to Steffen who took the time to explain and answer my remaining doubts about how sockets work. You guys really helped out here, probably saved my ESP32 project.